# How can I reference a shape by getting name of shape from a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, shapes

I would like to loop through a list of shapes by specific names which are given in a list of cells in Excel. To simplify, here is the problem for referring to the name of one shape only:

The name of a shape is "Star1" and given in cell A1.

In the VBA code, I could directly select the shape by `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Star1").Select` or `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Select`. However, I would like to indirectly select the shape by referring to the name given in cell A1

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Indirect("A1")).Select
```

This code does not work and wonder how it can be fixed.

Comment: Why not work with a `Range` object? `Dim rngShapeName as Range : Set rngShapeName = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") : ActiveSheet.Shapes(rngShapeName.Value).Select`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are looking for would look like this:-

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).Value).Select
or, if you prefer,
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, "A").Value).Select
or
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value).Select
```

In all of the above cases the shape is on Sheet1 and its name is on Sheet2. Both items could be on the same sheet, and either of the two (or both) could be the ActiveSheet and be addressed accordingly.

Comment: Could you describe a scenario when **'.Value'** could not be omitted especially in this case or provide a link to this issue.

Comment: A range is a number of cells. The smallest range has a single cell. A range has many properties, like the row where it is, the column, its colour, its font etc.etc. One of its properties is its Value which is either the value entered by the user or the result of a formula in the cell. The Value property is the default. Therefore `Range("A1").Value` is equivalent to `Range("A1")` in many circumstances but not in all.. For example, copying a cell is different from copying its value. Specifying the Value property when it is meant makes code clearer.

Comment: I know I always specify .Value in my code as well. For me it just makes the code easier to read.  I am constantly referring to object properties and like to set my code up for other people to read as well; always specifying the property being referenced, even the default, makes communicating the intent of the code clearer.