# How can I change the shape size of a shape by clicking another shape?

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple shapes that when clicked it's doing things in my Excel sheet (my code below).
But apart from these things I want to change the size of a shape that is positioned 2 cells to the right of the shape I'am clicking.
How can I do this without referring to the name of the shape I want to resize?

This is my code.

```
    Sub ArrowClick()
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
             .EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
             With .EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(9)
                 .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .Hidden
        End With
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: I've not tried this, but assuming it works it should be adaptable to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54275302/212869

Comment: Please, try the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next way. It will select the shape on the second column of the clicked shape row and double its width:

```
Sub ArrowClick()
    Dim nextSh As Shape
    Const sizeW As Double = 45   'use there your usual real width
    Const sizeH As Double = 14    'use there your usual real height
    
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
        .EntireRow.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
        With .EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(9)
                .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .Hidden
        End With
        Set nextSh = findNextSh(.Offset(0, 2).Address)
        If Not nextSh Is Nothing Then
           nextSh.placement = xlMove 'set the placemeny property to `Move but don't size with cells
            If nextSh.width = sizeW Then
               nextSh.width = sizeW * 2    'use here what size you need for changing the initial sizes
               nextSh.height = sizeH * 1.2
            Else
                nextSh.width = sizeW: nextSh.height = sizeH
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

```
Function findNextSh(strRange As String) As Shape
   Dim sh As Shape
   For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If sh.TopLeftCell.Address = strRange Then
            Set findNextSh = sh: Exit Function
        End If
   Next sh
End Function
```

Comment: Your cod was exactly what I needed so thank you for that. However, one thing I didn't thought of before, was that I needed a way to get the shape back to its original size again. This should happen when I click the same shape a second time. So basicaly, the shape should alternate its size from big to small and small to big and so on. I hope you could help me with this to?

Comment: Now, I do not have access to a laptop. Basically you should memorise both sizes in two Public variables. If looking difficult, I will show you tomorrow how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: @Neod Did you succeed adapting the code to work in two sequences? I can adapt it, but before that I would like to know if initial size of all involved such shapes is the same. In such a case, solution is simpler. Otherwise, it is still possible, but a little more complicated...

Comment: No, I didn't succeed. I had a thought that I could set a value to a cell and have this value as a reference if the shape is big or small. This cell could be in the same row and then just hide the column for those cells.
But I haven't tried it out and I'm not sure if it will work.
As for your question, the shapes are the same size, so it might make it easier.

Comment: @Neod Please, test the updated code and send some feedback. Do not omit to set your initial real shape(s) sizes in both constants (`sizeW` and `sizeH`).

Comment: It worked great.
The only thing I needed to do, was to get the shape size in points as it's set in centimeters within Excel.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Neod  Glad I could help!